# How to append numpy arrays in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like this, which I want to use to draw on an image.

```
points = np.array([[100, 140], [150, 235], [697, 300]], np.int32)
cv2.polylines(img, [points], 1, (255,255,255))
```

Could you please tell me how can I append this numpy array with more points?
I tried this way, but after that polylines doesn't work.

```
points = np.append(points, [333,111])
```

I get the following error:
"(-215:Assertion failed) p.checkVector(2, CV_32S) >= 0 in function 'cv::polylines'"

Comment: Use `np.concatenate` or one of the `stack` variants. These all take a list of arrays that you want to join.   `np.append` isn't very useful.

Comment: Did you look at `points` after the `append`?  What was its shape compared to the original  `points`.

Comment: _I tried this way, but after that polylines doesn't work._ What does that mean? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I was really tired, but you are right. I added the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing [`numpy.append`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html?highlight=append#numpy-append)'s third argument, which is `axis` and specifies the axis along which values are appended. If not provided, both arrays are flattened before use.

So you probably want this:

```
np.append(points, [[333, 111]], axis=0)
```

Which will give you this:

```
array([[100, 140],
       [150, 235],
       [697, 300],
       [333, 111]])
```

You might be wondering why the double square brackets in `[[333, 111]]`, and that's because the dimensions of both arrays must match, as stated on the docs.

Answer (score 1):

do you want to get this?

```
[[100,140],
[150,235],
[697,300],
[333,111]]
```

try vstack:

```
b = np.array( [  [333,111]   ] )
result = np.vstack (  (points,b)  )
```

Comment: I tried your solution too. It also works properly! Thank you!